# how can i compare,sort and finally print these four dictionaries with order of "points" value?

Tags: python

there are four dictionaries below and i want print their items with order of points key, wins and goal difference values for example with below values of "points" key , team 2 and team 4 are same and also their "wins" are same but team4 goal difference is more so team 4 dic must be printed first and then team 2 then team1 and finally team 3 , in fact i want sort these four dictionary by order of (points,wins and goal difference to print in result.

```
team1= {"wins":2, "loses":2, "draws":1, "goal difference":3, "points":4}

team2= {"wins":3, "loses":4, "draws":5, "goal difference":1, "points":6}

team3= {"wins":2, "loses":1, "draws":1, "goal difference":4, "points":2}

team4= {"wins":3, "loses":1, "draws":4, "goal difference":6, "points":6}
```

i couldnt reach any effective solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them in a list and sort them using a key function. However, a problem you're going to run into is that none of the lists identify which team it is. Right now they identified by their individual variable names. So before you sort the dictionaries, add identifying information for each team. Here we just add a key `id` numbered starting with 1, which matches the suffix of the variable names. If you had the team names you could use those instead.

```
from operator import itemgetter

teams = [team1, team2, team3, team4]
for id, team in enumerate(teams, 1):
    team["id"] = id
teams.sort(key=itemgetter("points", "wins", "goal difference"), reverse=True)
```

Comment: thanks this method worked but i have one more question. assume that two teams are same in "points" and "wins" and "goal difference"  and required to sort as per alphabetic order , is there any option for this ?

Comment: You'd need to put the names in the dictionaries, but you could just add `"name"` (or whatever you named that field) as another parameter to `itemgetter`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `sorted` with key parameter

Pythons `sorted` with the key parameter can help you define multiple criteria for sorting. Here, the criteria is a lambda function that takes each dict, and uses the "points" as the first criteria and "wins" & "goal difference" as the second and third criteria, respectively and sorts the list of dictionaries accordingly.

Try this -

```
#Store your dicts into a list
l = [team1, team2, team3, team4]

#Use the base python's "sorted" with key parameter
#reverse = True for descending order
s = sorted(l, key = lambda x: (x['points'], x['wins'], x['goal difference']), reverse=True)
print(s)
```

```
[{'wins': 3, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 4, 'goal difference': 6, 'points': 6},
 {'wins': 3, 'loses': 4, 'draws': 5, 'goal difference': 1, 'points': 6},
 {'wins': 2, 'loses': 2, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 3, 'points': 4},
 {'wins': 2, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 4, 'points': 2}]
```

---

#### Bonus (sorting order each criteria independently)

A quick suggestion, a better way might be to have an additional parameter with the team name, in each dictionary, instead of worrying about a uniquely named variable for each of them. So you may want to define your list of teams and statistics something like this -

```
l = [
     {'name': 'team1', 'wins': 2, 'loses': 2, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 3, 'points': 4},
     {'name': 'team2', 'wins': 3, 'loses': 4, 'draws': 5, 'goal difference': 1, 'points': 6},
     {'name': 'team3', 'wins': 2, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 4, 'points': 2},
     {'name': 'team4', 'wins': 3, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 4, 'goal difference': 6, 'points': 6}
    ]

s = sorted(l, key = lambda x: (x['points'], x['wins'], x['goal difference']), reverse=True)
print(s)
```

```
[{'name': 'team4', 'wins': 3, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 4, 'goal difference': 6, 'points': 6},
 {'name': 'team2', 'wins': 3, 'loses': 4, 'draws': 5, 'goal difference': 1, 'points': 6},
 {'name': 'team1', 'wins': 2, 'loses': 2, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 3, 'points': 4},
 {'name': 'team3', 'wins': 2, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 4, 'points': 2}]
```

This makes it easier to scale and much more readable code. Now, if you want to have each sorting criteria have its own sorting order (ascending or descending), you can actually control that without having to add the `reverse=True` parameter by adding `-` sign infront of each (works for numeric).

```
#Sort points -> descending
#Sort wins -> descending
#Sort goals -> ascending
s = sorted(l, key = lambda x: (-x['points'], -x['wins'], x['goal difference']))
print(s)
```

```
[{'name': 'team2', 'wins': 3, 'loses': 4, 'draws': 5, 'goal difference': 1, 'points': 6}, 
 {'name': 'team4', 'wins': 3, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 4, 'goal difference': 6, 'points': 6}, 
 {'name': 'team1', 'wins': 2, 'loses': 2, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 3, 'points': 4}, 
 {'name': 'team3', 'wins': 2, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 4, 'points': 2}]
```

Comment: thanks this method worked  and i didnt know lambda needed to study more and i have one more question. assume that two teams are same in "points" and "wins" and "goal difference" and required to sort as per alphabetic order , is there any option for this with your lambda method?

Comment: glad to help. lambda is just another way to define quick functions. here is something you can refer to - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

Comment: for your second case, like i mentioned, you can have a field which is 'name':'team1' and if you pass that as the 4th parameter, it will sort alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

You can key on multiple items using an [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> key = itemgetter("points", "wins", "goal difference")
>>> sorted(teams, key=key, reverse=True)
[
    {'wins': 3, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 4, 'goal difference': 6, 'points': 6},
    {'wins': 3, 'loses': 4, 'draws': 5, 'goal difference': 1, 'points': 6},
    {'wins': 2, 'loses': 2, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 3, 'points': 4},
    {'wins': 2, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 4, 'points': 2}
]
```

Comment: thanks, this method worked too, i didnt know itemgetter , in fact i didnt know operator library.